# "Simplified" Newton method of finding roots.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This pertains to Edwards's Advance Calculus of Several Variables. Chapter III.

Given a real-valued function $f(x)$, continuously differentiable and
monotonic on the interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that it changes
sign between $a$ and $b$, the sequence ${\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}}$
defined by $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime}(x_{n})}$ and
$x_{0}\in[a,b]$ converges to a root of $f$. Edwards doesn't offer
a proof, and the fact is only used as a motivating example.

He demonstrates that the modified sequence $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}$
may fail to converge. For example $f(x)=\sin x$ will fail to converge
if $x_{0}=\frac{\tan x}{2}$ because $x_{1}=x_{0}-\frac{\sin x_{0}}{\cos x_{0}}=-x_{0}$
so $x_{2}=-x_{0}+\frac{\sin x_{0}}{\cos x_{0}}=x_{0}$. He then goes
on to prove that for $f^{\prime}>0$ and $M=\max f^{\prime}([a,b])$,
the modification $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{M}$ will produce
a convergant sequence.

He then goes on to solve $f[x]=y$ for $x$ when $y$ is given ``near''
some $f[x_{0}]=y_{0}$ with known values for $x_{0}$, $f^{\prime}(x_{0})$
and $y_{0}$. In this case he uses $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})-y}{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}$
as the generic term in the sequence. But $g(x)=f(x)-y$ leads to $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{g(x_{n})}{g^{\prime}(x_{0})}$.
The sequence of these terms should converge to the same value of $x$,
where $f(x)=y$ and $f(x)=0$.

Is $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})-y}{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}$ not suseptible
to the same vulnerability as is $x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has the same vulnerability.  The problems tend to arise when you have stationary points between $x_0$ and the closest root.  Or when $f'(x_0)$ is near $0.$

[image]

Comment: Edwards restricts the domain and range of the latter sequence to "some neighborhood" when proving it necessarily converges.  I still lack intuitive confidence in the second proof.